# Iptables empty but the rule exists

Tags: networking, server, iptables

I'm running a web service that listen to port 3000. Then I added a redirect rule in my iptable as follows:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

This works perfectly but:

1. Why there is no rules displayed running `sudo iptables -L`?

[image]

2. Why is the rule persistent? after rebooting the server the redirect from 80 to 3000 still works, according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84781/iptables-resets-when-server-reboots) I need to use `iptables-persistent` which I'm not using.

Comment: So you didn't install iptables-persistent?

Answer (score 6):

1.) The command:

```
sudo iptables -L
```

only displays the main iptables chains, however the command you listed would have been added to the `nat` table. You need to use:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -L
```

Myself, I would use these versions:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L
sudo iptables -v -x -n -L
```

2.) There are many ways to make the rules auto apply after re-boot. The `iptables-persistent` method is just one method (which I do not use, by the way). We would need some more information to be able to help further.